# Error installing MySQLDb on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, python3

I am using python3

I am trying to install MySQLdb,

```
$ pip3  install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-g34d6t3j/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-build-g34d6t3j/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

so I tried installing ConfigParser and discovered ConfigParser is renamed to configParser in python3, now I installed `configparser` on `python3`.

```
~$ pip3 install configParser
Collecting configParser
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/2a/95ed0501cf5d8709490b1d3a3f9b5cf340da6c433f896bbe9ce08dbe6785/configparser-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: configParser
Successfully installed configParser-4.0.2
```

but still I get the error saying:

```
~$ pip3  install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-qkip1b53/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-build-qkip1b53/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qkip1b53/mysql-python/
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql-python` is not compatible with Python3 and can't be installed using `pip3`.

Use [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) (package `python3-mysqldb` in Ubuntu) or see [the Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL) for some more possibilities to access MySQL from Python.

Comment: anyway I got it working using pymysql.